# A generic metric on $X\cup\mathbb Z$

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

$\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}$Let $(X,d_X)$ be a countable metric space such that $X\cap\mathbb Z=\{0\}$.

**Problem.** Is there a metric $d$ on the union $Y=X\cup\mathbb Z$ such that

- $d(x,y)=d_X(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$;
- $d(n,m)=\abs{n-m}$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb Z$;
- $d(x,y)\notin d_X[X^2]\cup\mathbb N$ for any points $x\in X\setminus\mathbb Z$ and $y\in\mathbb Z\setminus X$;
- for any distinct pairs $(x,y),(x',y')\in (X\setminus\mathbb Z)\times(\mathbb Z\setminus X)$ we have $d(x,y)\ne d(x',y')$?

So, the problem is to find an extension of the metrics of the spaces $X$ and $\mathbb Z$ to a metric on the union $X\cup\mathbb Z$ so that all distances between points of the sets $X\setminus \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z\setminus X$ are pairwise distinct and do not belong to the set $d_X[X^2]\cup\mathbb N$.

**Remark.** If $r:=\inf (d_X[X^2]\setminus\{0\})>0$, then a desirable metric $d$ on $X\cup\mathbb Z$ can be defined by the formula
$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases} d_X(x,y)&\text{if $x,y\in X$;}\\
\abs{x-y}&\text{if $x,y\in \mathbb Z$;}\\
d_X(x,0)+\abs y-\varepsilon_+(x)&\text{if $x\in X\setminus\{0\}$ and $y\in \mathbb N$;}\\
d_X(x,0)+\abs y-\varepsilon_-(x)&\text{if $x\in X\setminus\{0\}$ and $y\in -\mathbb N$;}\\
d_X(y,0)+\abs x-\varepsilon_+(y)&\text{if $x\in \mathbb N$ and $y\in X\setminus\{0\}$;}\\
d_X(y,0)+\abs x-\varepsilon_-(y)&\text{if $x\in -\mathbb N$ and $y\in X\setminus\{0\}$}
\end{cases}
$$
for suitable injective functions $\varepsilon_+,\varepsilon_-:X\to (0,r)$ such that $\varepsilon_\pm(x)< \varepsilon_\pm(y)$ for any points $x,y\in X$ with $d_X(0,x)< d_X(0,y)$.

**Added in Edit.** However, the general case seems to be still open.

Comment: Noticed where? Assuming it has an affirmative answer, it'd be reassuringly pro-social to let us see it.

Comment: @jdc There was an answer by JoelDavidHamkins which he later deleted because it was incomplete.

Comment: @jdc I have deleted my remark in "Added in Edit" because of a gap in my argument for the general case. Nonetheless,  the case $\inf (d_X[X^2]\setminus\{0\})>0$ seems to be valid (with monotone $\varepsilon_+$ and $\varepsilon_-$).

Comment: @TarasBanakh I see, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: There is a naive and hand-waving idea to show that the required extensions $d$ constitute a comeager set in the Polish space of all compatible extensions of $d_X$ from $X$ and $|\cdot |$ from $\mathbb Z$. It seems that then we have to show some finite-based deviation possibility. I think we can discuss the details at out meeting at the Tuesday.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I also thought this way (and without success), unfortunately.

Comment: Are you asking about $\mathbb{Z}$ as the second metric space, rather than some arbitrary countable $\mathbf{Y}$ because that's the case you are interested in, or because you know it doesn't work in general?

Comment: @Arno I was interested in $\mathbf Z$ as a specific case but now I see that the general case can be resolved too, using the approach suggested by Pietro Majer in his deleted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The affirmative answer to this problem follows from a general result on extension of graph metrics. In the following definitions, the unordered pair $\{x,y\}$ of two elements $x,y$ is denoted by $xy$.

A *graph metric* on a set $X$ is any function $d:\mathrm{dom}[d]\to\mathbb R_+$ defined on a subset $\mathrm{dom}[d]\subseteq [X]^2:=\{A\subseteq X:|A|=2\}$ such that the following two conditions are satisfied:

1. for every $x,y\in X$ there exist points $x_0,\dots,x_n\in X$ such that $x_0=x$, $x_n=y$ and $\{x_{i-1}x_i:0<i\le n\}\subseteq \mathrm{dom}[d]$;
2. for every $xy\in\mathrm{dom}[X]$ we have $d(xy)\le\hat d(x,y)$,
   where $\hat d:X\times X\to\mathbb R$ is the pseudometric on $X$, defined by the formula
   $$\hat d(x,y):=\inf\Big\{\sum_{i=1}^nd(x_{i-1}x):xy=x_0x_n\;\wedge\;\{x_{i-1}x_i:0<i\le n\}\subseteq\mathrm{dom}[d]\Big\}.$$

A graph metric $d:\mathrm{dom}[d]\to\mathbb R_+$ is a *full metric* if $\mathrm{dom}[d]=[X]^2$.

A graph metric $d:\mathrm{dom}[d]\to\mathbb R_+$ is *floppy* if for every $xy\in[X]^2\setminus\mathrm{dom}[d]$ we have $\check d(x,y)<\hat d(x,y)$, where $$\check d(x,y):=\sup\big\{\min\{0,d(uv)-\hat d(u,x)-\hat d(v,y)\}:uv\in \mathrm{dom}[X]^2\big\}.$$

The proof of the following theorem can be found in [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.12162).

> **Theorem.** Let $d:\mathrm{dom}[d]\to\mathbb R_+$ be a floppy graph metric on a set $X$ and $(D_{xy})_{xy\in[X]^2\setminus\mathrm{dom}[d]}$ be an indexed family of dense sets in $\mathbb R_+$. If the set $[X]^2\setminus\mathrm{dom}[d]$ is at most countable, then there exists a full metric $\tilde d:[X]^2\to\mathbb R_+$ such that $d\subseteq\tilde d$ and $\tilde d(xy)\in D_{xy}$ for every $xy\in [X]^2\setminus\mathrm{dom}[d]$.

This theorem easily implies the affirmative answer to the MO-question because $d_X\cup d_{\mathbb Z}$ is a floppy graph metric on the union $X\cup\mathbb Z$.

> **Question.** Is the above Theorem indeed new, or it has been already proved by some classics (Frechet, Hausdorff, Menger, Sierpinski...)?

**Remark.** The Theorem cannot be generalized to floppy graph metrics on uncountable sets.

Answer (score 1):

Let's apply the classical favorite Stefan Banach's method:

The set $\ M\ $ of all metrics $\ \delta\ $ that extend the given
metrics $\ d\ $ in $\ X,\ $ and the standard metrics in
$\ \mathbb Z\ $ in $\ \mathbb Z,\ $ form a **non-empty** functional
complete metric space with respect to the uniform distance between
functions.

The 3rd and 4th OP's conditions (they feature the symbols $\ \notin\ $
and $\ \ne)\ $ amount to defining a countable number of open subsets of
space $\ M.\ $ The (countable) intersection of all these open dense
subsets of $\ M\ $ is a (non-empty) dense G$_\delta$ in $\ M\ $ --
but this is the set of all required solutions, such solutions exist.

Comment: The main question to your solution is why those open sets are dense in your functional complete metric space of metrics?

Comment: Taras, I am very-very slow (and dense :-) )these days but I will try to address your q. anyway.